# VBA - Copy range from 300 closed workbooks onto one main consolidated workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

Please help with writing the formula to pull data from 300 closed workbooks (and I don't want to open any of those 300 workbooks).  Description of project:  There are 300 excel timesheets.  Need copy the range (A1:AC51) from each timesheet onto the main calculation workbook, calculate payroll, and then copy payroll result to another worksheet in the same main workbook.  The trick here is to do it without opening the 300 excel timesheets.  I wrote the code below, but I'm stuck on how to write the formula to pull the data from a closed workbook, please help?  Again,

- There are 300 excel timesheets (closed workbooks), Sheets("EmpInput")
- There is one main calculation workbook (open), Sheets("Main")
- Objective:  Copy the exact same range from each timesheet, calculate payroll, copy result to another sheet, Sheets("Results")

Thank you so much in advance!

```
Public Sub GetTimesheetData()

     Dim fsoFileObject As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
     Dim employeeTimesheet As File
     Dim folderPath As String
     Dim nextEmpty As Long

     folderPath = "C:\GatherTimesheets\"    '<<<<< There are 300 excel timesheets in this folder.

     For Each employeeTimesheet In fso.folderPath.Files  '<<<< Is this correct?

        If empoyeeTimesheet.Name Like "*.xls" Then
               Sheets("Main").Select
               With Range("A1:AC51")
                  .Formula = "='C:\GatherTimesheets\" & employeeTimesheet   '<<<< How to write this formula??
                  .Value = .Value
               End With

               nextEmpty = Sheets("Results").Range("D65444").End(xlUp).Row + 1

               Sheets("Main").Range("CS1:DF1").Copy
               With Sheets("StagingRaw").Range("D" & nextEmpty)
                  .PasteSpecial xlValues
                  Application.CutCopyMode = False
               End With
         End If

     Next employeeTimesheet

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to open the files, can't avoid that step.

Comment: Indeed, you can't avoid opening the file - but that doesn't mean your productivity stops because 300 spreadsheets are popping up on your display.  My recommendation would be to create a very simple useform so you can start, stop, pause, and resume the program and display the job process while each workbook is opened in windowless mode.

Comment: For some code, see [Open Excel file for reading with VBA without display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579797/open-excel-file-for-reading-with-vba-without-display). I also suggest displaying a count or file name in the [status bar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.statusbar) to show progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is `='C:\Path\[SourceFileName.xlsx]SourceSheetName'!A1:Z9`.

Try `Range("A1:AC51").FormulaArray = "='C:\GatherTimesheets\[" & employeeTimesheet & "]EmpInput'!A1:AC51"`.

For more info see [Range.FormulaArray property (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulaarray) and [Create an external reference (link) to a cell range in another workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f). Also, use [Option Explicit](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx) to avoid typos like `empoyeeTimesheet`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Scenography!!